# Unable to set a new variable after using the random command in Python

Tags: python, random

I'm very new to Python and I'm having an issue setting a new variable after using the random command.

Here is my sample code:

```
import random

foo = ['a', 'b']
print("foo is: " + random.choice(foo))

if foo == 'a':
    randomLetter = 'a'
else:
    randomLetter = 'b'

print(randomLetter)
```

No matter what `foo` equals, `randomLetter` always equals b.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: You are not setting `foo`. If you print `foo` you will see that it is `['a', 'b']`. You maybe want to make `foo = random.choice(foo)`

Comment: When you say `foo = ['a', 'b']`, you're saying that `foo` is a list of two items. So when you get to `if foo == 'a'`, that's the same as checking if the list `['a', 'b']` is the same thing as the string `'a'`.  Obviously this will never be the case; one is a list and the other is a string.  The command `print("foo is: " + random.choice(foo))` randomly picks an item from your list and prints it, but it doesn't make any changes to the list itself.

`random.choice(foo)` just picks a random item from that list to print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

foo = ['a', 'b']
randomly_selected = random.choice(foo)
print("foo is: " + randomly_selected)

if randomly_selected == 'a':
    randomLetter = 'a'
else:
    randomLetter = 'b'

print(randomLetter)
```

`foo` is a list containing two alphabets. Using `random`, if you wish to select a random element, you can do so using `random.choice(foo)`. But, if you want to use the output of this elsewhere in your code, you will have to store the result in a different variable and then check condition in the code, accordingly.

Comment: You solution worked. I had to fix the spelling. ```radomly``` to ```randomly``` on line 4.

Comment: Sorry for the typo! Corrected it.

Comment: Did it in the morning. Thanks again for helping.

Answer (score 2):

random.choice needs to be assigned to a variable...

```
letters=["a","b"]
randomLetter = random.choice(letters)
print(randomLetter)
```

What happened in your code is, that foo was never equal to "a" so it jumped in the else condition

```
randomLetter = 'b'
```

Where you assigned randomLetter its value, wich is then printed